# Killing a thread or an alternative

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, nsthread

Is there any way I can kill a thread spawn through:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(serverFetchInThread) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

The scenario I am working on is that in my main thread I am letting user enter data in my search bar and what ever user is typing I need to send to server for searching in a separate thread. Now, if user changes his selection by deleting old data and entering new data I do not want the previous thread to waste its time, kill it and spawn a new thread with new data.

Be there any other better way to handle this situation, please guide me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to kill a thread from another thread.  And for good reason as there is no way to do so in a fashion where the targeted thread is killed without risk of crashing the app.

To directly answer your question;  you need to have some kind of a flag that indicates to the thread that it should stop doing whatever it is doing and exit.

However, a couple of questions are raised by your question:

First, why are you using threads and not using GCD?  Concurrency via GCD or NSOperation is the generally recommended way to solve such problems.

Secondly, if you are talking to a server, are you using HTTP (most of the time, that is the case)?  If so, why not directly use the asynchronous features of NSURL and friends?

Comment: Thank you. I am using async HTTP connection. Can you please throw some more light on using a flag and indicating the thread to stop itself. I will be setting up the flag in the main thread, right? How can I read that in separate thread.

Comment: NSHTTPConnection can be stopped just by calling it's `cancel` method.

Comment: Thats right but once a asyc server call is made in a thread how can I call a cancel method on it from main thread.

Comment: Use a BOOL;  either a global or an instance variable.   Set it from the main thread and periodically check it in your background thread.   Avoid polling, though.

Comment: However, if you are using NSHTTPConnection, then there is no need to spawn a thread to do the connection.

Comment: I don't see NSHTTPConnection, only NSURLConnection.

Comment: @CocoaFu: Yeah its NSURLConnection and bbum is right. We need not to spawn a Thread for making this connection.

Answer (score 1):

Have a good look at using [`NSOperationQueue`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/).

You can subclass `NSOperation` it to wrap up your server communications, and even make that  queue serial (maximum operations = 1).

If a server operation is not yet finished and user has generated more input, you can cancel the existing one, and add the new one.

Due to the effect of the `NSOperation` wrapping your connection, you can just use the simple synchronous version and keep the connection handling very straightforward.

Also worth mentioning is compatibility. I would prefer to use GCD and blocks, but for compatibility, `NSOperationQueue` is required.