# Is there a way to kill a hanging thread?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using a third party framework, which in rare cases does not respond anymore, if the internet connection is lost. My tests showed that when I am connected via WiFi on my home network and I start using the app and when the network changes from WiFi to the carrier network, the thread does not respond, if it was exchanging data at that very moment. 
Of course I got in touch with the vendor of the framework to fix this, however, it will take some time, until I will get the patch. 
In the meantime I would like to implement a work-around, so the user does not have to deal with a non-responding app, especially as this is a no-go for the app approval.
My question: Is there a way I can monitor such a thread and terminate it after a timeout?

Or would anyone have another solution approach for this issue? I know about the reachability framework of Apple, but as far as I understand the framework, it is a detection tool only, which in my case would not solve my issue, right?

Thanks, René

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443858/killing-a-thread-or-an-alternative

Comment: Agree with the duplicate, the linked question answered mine too. Thx